# Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined'

Tags: angular

I encountered a problem that my function does not recognize the `IdUtilisateur` which is in a parameter in the function `navigate()` and which was retrieved from the input field.

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenficationService } from 'src/app/services/AuthenficationService/Authentification.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'bm-authentification',
  templateUrl: './authentification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./authentification.component.css']
})
export class AuthentificationComponent implements OnInit {
  IdUtilisateur : Number;
  constructor(private router: Router,private service: AuthenficationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  // cette méthode retourne true si elle trouve l utulisateur cherché par son id sur le serveur sinon elle retourne false 
  Authentification(id):any{
    this.service.getUtilisateur(id).subscribe(response=>{
      console.log("response:",response);
      if (response.length !=0){
      console.log(true ) ; 
      return true ;
      }
        else {
          console.log(false) ; 
          return false ;
        }
    },error=>{
      console.log("error",error);
    });
  
  }
navigate(IdUtilisateur){
  if(this.Authentification(IdUtilisateur)== true){
    this.router.navigate(['/accueil']) ;
  }
  else {
    this.router.navigate(['/authentification']) ;
  }
  
  }

}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url('http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/a/5/d/544750.jpg');background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;background-position: top;margin:0;background-attachment:scroll;height:1000px ; width:auto;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>Sign In</h3>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end social_icon">
                    <span><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></span>
                    <span><i class="fab fa-google-plus-square"></i></span>
                    <span><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="IdUtilisateur" name="IdUtilisateur" placeholder="IdUtilisateur"  required>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row align-items-center remember">
                        <input type="checkbox">Remember Me {{IdUtilisateur}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn" (click)="navigate(IdUtilisateur)" [disabled]="(!IdUtilisateur)">
                    

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                    Don't have an account?<a href="#">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's done @Liam

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognize"? What is the value of the parameter when the function is called after entering a string in your input field?

Comment: @MikeS.     when the parameter "IdUtilisateur"is  called in the function navigate(IdUtilisateur) , the IdUtilisateur i get it from the input :  <input type="text" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="IdUtilisateur" name="IdUtilisateur" placeholder="IdUtilisateur"  required>

Comment: I meant the value of the parameter. If it's `undefined` you may need to add a property in your component called `IdUtilisateur` if it's not there already.

Comment: @MikeS
I did it but it didn't work I update all my files on the publication so that you can understand

Comment: Nowhere in this code do you call `toString` so where's that? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: in my service  in this function getUtilisateur(idUtilisateur:number):Observable<Array<any>> {
    let params = new Map<string, string>();
    params.set("numeroEmploye", idUtilisateur.toString())
    return this.httpService.getObject<Array<any>>(this.baseUrl, false, params);
  }

Comment: Can't you provide some additional context? Isn't there a stacktrace? If you are in development mode you should get the source file and the line number.  By the way, ´console.log(true)´  will quickly get useless as the application grow because you will forget what ´true´ is related to. ´console.log("Connected", true)´ look better to me.

Comment: @C.Champagne   thanks i don't have the problem of toString now but when i press "Login" that don't change page to navigate and there is no fault  in the consol

Answer (score 0):

```
IdUtilisateur : Number = 0;
```

I think the value was never getting set to IdUtilisateur so it was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing *asynchronous* and *synchronous* code.

`Authentification` has not actually made the HTTP call yet when it is supposed to return its value.

You should thus redirect in your `subscribe` lambda or call navigate from there but I don't see the advantage in your case.

```js
Authentification(id): any {
    this.service.getUtilisateur(id).subscribe(response => {
        console.log("response:", response);
        if (response.length != 0) {
            console.log("Authenticated -> redirect to accueil");
            this.router.navigate(['/accueil']);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Authenticated -> redirect to accueil");
            this.router.navigate(['/authentification']) ;
        }
    }, error => {
        console.log("error", error);
    });
}
```

By the way, I have few remarks:

- It is just a convention but methods and properties in Typescript don't begin with a capital letter.
- It should be a verb (whatever the language) otherwise it is confusing.
  I suggest you to rename `Authentification` as `authenticate` (or `authentifier` if you prefer using french words).
- Use the `any` type as less a possible. If you had used `boolean` as return type of `Authentification` you would have get directly an error and noticed something was wrong.